# Browser: How to cache large data yet enable small parts to be updated?

Tags: reactjs, performance, caching, frontend

I have a list of 20k employees to display in a React table. When the admin user changes one, I want the change reflected in the table - even if she does a reload - but I don't want to re-fetch all 20k including the unchanged 19 999.

(The table is of course paged and shows max N at once but I still need all 20k to support search and filtering, which is impractical to do server side for various reasons)

The solution I can think of is to set caching headers for /api/employees so that it is cached for e.g. one hour and have another endpoint, /api/employees?changedSince= and somehow ensure that server knows which employees have been changed. But I am sure somebody has already implemented a solution(s) for this...

Thank you!

Comment: *Clarification*:  I do not control the database. I only control the browser and my "frontend backend" which calls the external service that has the employee data and that can 1.give me a page of the data or 2.give me a particular employee

Answer (score 0):

A timestamp solution would be the best, and simplest, way to implement it. It would only require a small amount of extra data to be stored and would provide the most maintainable and expandable solution.

All you would need to do is update the timestamp when an item in the list is updated. Then, when the page loads for the first time, access `/api/employees`, then periodically request `/api/employees?changedSince` to return all of the changed rows in the table, for React to then update.

In terms of caching the main `/api/employees` endpoint, I’m not sure how much benefit you would gain from doing that, but it depends on how often the data is updated.

Comment: The problem is I do not control the database and 1.cant add timestamp to each row 2.there isn't API to fetch records changed after a date. I only control the browser and my "frontend backend" which callas the external service that has the employee data.

Comment: Then you would have to create your own endpoints that checks for changes and stores a timestamp that you can relate to a row in the table.

Comment: Yes, or perhaps keep the info on the client in a cookie or local storage. Somebody must have implemented this in React already?

Comment: Cookies or local storage may not be large enough for all of that data and even if it would fit the theoretical size limit, a browser could still clear it if felt it was too large and the user was running out of space, for example. They aren't the most robust forms of storage and if you could help it, I don't think that they are the best solution, particularly if it is going to be used by lots of people across different devices and browsers.

Comment: Not to store the data, only IDs of the changed records so that I could fetch them individually after fetching the (cached, outdated) full employees set

Comment: If you could store it like that, then that would be a good way. The point I was trying to make was that you can’t necessarily rely on cookies or local storage. You have to treat it as a bonus that they are present, rather than completely necessary. Depending on the rate at which the items are updated, it still may or may not be a useful solution. It would help if you could give us a clearer insight into your situation.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying your a in control of the frontends backend, imho this backend should cache all of the upstream data in its own (SQL or whatever) database. The backend then can expose a proper api (with pagination and search). 
The backend can also implement some logic to identify which rows have changed.
If the frontend needs live updates about changes you can use some technology that allows bi-directional communication (SignalR if your backend is .NET based, or something like socket.io if you have a node backend, or even plain websockets)

Comment: Thank you, yes, that is an option I'm considering though I'm not happy about adding yet another layer of caching with all its problems.

Comment: if you cache large datasets inside the browser, you still have this layer... in the browser... which is imho a less good option than having an api. If you know backend stuff or someone who can execute that it is probably the "best" solution. Caching large datasets inside a browser is not a good solution, i.e. as there are (storage) limitations. However you need to take into account your skill-set, so if you feel very uncomfortable writing such an api, the browser might be a better option.